# SSRS pie chart legend

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to create a legend for my pie chart which includes the category and the %. I want it to look like something below

```
ABC    5%
ABDE   10%
CJDJD  85%
```

What I've attempted to try is by using a fixed length amount, i.e. 15 then I minus it from the length of the category. This figure is then used to add the required number of spaces before the percentages are added.

This however hasn't helped and the percentages are still out of alignment as each character length isn't the same. For example, you can have two words with the same amount of characters, but one word will take up more space than the other.

Does anyone know how I can workout around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font, size, style, and color of legend text on the Font page of the Legend Properties dialog box.

By default, the legend text is not optimized to fit the legend area. To cause the legend text to automatically fit the allocated space, set the AutoFitTextDisabled property to False and set a minimum font size for the MinFontSize property to the lowest font size that you think will be presentable and still allow for legend optimization.

Comment: Setting the AutoFixTextDisabled doesn't help. I tried using a monospaced font, and that helped the trick, but unfortunately I need to stick with the original font we used. Doesn't look like anything can be done so may not be able to align the percentages.

Comment: What you could do is to use a textbox and write html into the expression. This way you can use different formats, styles etc... within the same textbox. But I dont think this will work with a legend. Take a look here https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/10/31/using-different-formats-within-a-single-textbox-in-ssrs.html